# Remove all columns that are of a certain value in a specific row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a way to remove all columns from my pandas df based on the value of a single row, e.g., return a new df with all rows but only those columns that are zero in row X.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `loc` and `iloc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 20, 30, 4, 0],
              'b':[1, 0, 3, 4, 0],
              'c':[1, 3, 7, 7, 5],
              'd':[1, 8, 3, 8, 5],
              'e':[1, 11, 3, 4, 0]})


df.loc[:, df.iloc[4,:] == 0]


   a  b  e
0  1  1  1
1  2  0  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
4  0  0  0
```

Comment: Nice, that's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way. Any better/quicker/more pythonian/pandas solution anyone?

```
zero_cols = df1['X' ==  0 
df2 = df1.loc[:,zero_cols == True]
```